# How can IntelliJ and Flash symbol library work together?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, intellij-idea, flash-cs5

If I'm using IntelliJ Idea as my IDE for code that's being used by an fla that I'm compiling with Flash, is there a way I can tell IntelliJ what objects exist in the symbol that I'm writing a class file for so it doesn't treat references to these objects as undefined?

Example:
I have a Flash project in Flash CS5 with a MovieClip in the library which is linked to MyClass, an external class file.  The MovieClip has a TextField named myTextField.

When I edit the class file in IntelliJ, it complains about references to myTextField because it has no way of knowing about it.

Is there a way to clue in IntelliJ?  Can I just declare myTextField in the class file, or will that interfere with the instance that's already in the MovieClip?

Comment: Go to the publish settings of the your .fla document and tick Export SWC. You can then link the generated .swc file as a library in IntelliJ and you should get autocompletion on the symbols exported for actionscript

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for.  The fla is including the code I'm editing in IntelliJ and I'm using Flash to compile the swf.  Symbols in the fla's library are set to use class files that I'm editing in IntelliJ, and those symbols have MovieClips within them that I'd like to reference within the class files.  (More for proper typing than for autocomplete.)  If I declare a variable in the class that has the same name as objects within the associated symbol, I get runtime errors.  The best I can do is this[ 'mc_name' ] which is untyped.

Comment: I see. For really basic projects I don't mind using the actionscript editor in flash since it how has autocomplete, although it's still no replacement for a decent IDE. Personally I've worked for a while using workflow like yours: use an IDE, but compile an FLA as my main project(using a Document Class), but I don't think it's the best to be honest. Sometimes you can run into issues when extending classes that were exported from actionscript and so on. I think keeping the project as pure actionscript, compiled with the actionscript compiler in a decent IDE is a far cleaner option...

Comment: ...using Flash just to create/update/export assets

Comment: the way you're using IntelliJ with Flash atm means IntelliJ will never know the instance names you've setup in the IDE, so no autocompletion/etc. Using the the .swc approach will sort this issue and another advantage is, the swc is already compiled, meaning you won't compile the assets every single time you make a change in code: code and assets will be separated

Comment: Thanks.  For my own projects, I prefer to compile using the IDE and embed assets in the project as needed, but I frequently get projects from outside contractors in which I don't have time for a major overhaul and would prefer to use the IDE to edit the AS files (for a number of reasons) but since IntelliJ can't see the classes in the fla's library, it flags a lot of references as errors.

Comment: I see, that sounds messy as I presume everyone works in his/her own style. Wish there was a magic tool to easily import a Flash project into a decent IDE

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your FLA publish settings to allow you to declare your instances in your class files. Try this:

http://www.wastedpotential.com/flash-as3-stop-using-automatically-declare-stage-instances/

If you follow these steps, you can declare your instances as properties in your classes. Your FLA will compile and IntelliJ will stop choking on them.